# How to accomplish stongly-typed ids in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

A strongly-typed id would make it more difficult to pass the wrong id as a parameter to a function. E.g. `getThingById(notAThing.id)` is an easy mistake to make if both `Thing` and `NotAThing` have the same type of `id`.

Here's a first crack it but in the end `Id<TModel, TId>` are both `number`, so it does not accomplish the goal. How can this be altered so that the final two function calls fail?

```
type Thing = { id: Id<Thing> };
type NotAThing = { id: Id<NotAThing> };

type Id<TModel, TId = number> = TId;

const thing: Thing = {
  id: 123,
};

const notAThing: NotAThing = {
  id: 456,
};

function getThing(id: Id<File>) {
  return "here's the thing";
}

function getNotAThing(id: Id<NotAThing>) {
    return "here's the not a thing";
}


// This works.
getThing(thing.id);
getNotAThing(notAThing.id);


// How to make it not work (fail compilation) if you pass the "wrong type of id"?
getThing(notAThing.id);
getNotAThing(thing.id);
```

[Ready to test in the Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAKgFgSwHYHMoF4oG8oICYBcUAkngDzzIoB8UAvgNwCwAUKJFAHID2wAgpVQZsuQiXI9+gmvWYtW7aKQoBZbnggAbADSxSwpAFcAtgCMIAJ1qYYpOawDG3JAGdgUYIlRFpwrKyhRIgBGACYAZm1WRlZHZzcoJF4BLxQiSRSqPwCgqAAWAFYANiiWGPkWADNDJAdgBGcoFAhgaQAKfCJlADEETQhqAEpsHIsWwwskKAAiOEsIAHIXDzmVqmm5OliqmrqGqebgDPbO8TJj1KGRlkDAseAJqdn5pZXoJPcAQzXUDejt1gAekBsEQywA7twLABrFwAOlYh3aniocPwgzkhwuVDaH0yqDReAxAJYwKgAAluOCPNwoMZPtDoAh3B8oJCYVA2pVPn0oE5jGA+p96s5hghKlAQNxDFAwJ8XMtPNBpuCLM40IooNwJfhpgB+REtdp46SE4ksLHJZGpM0MIA)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The concept is called "opaque types". It is a type similar to an existing one (like a string or a number) but not interchangeable with it.

There is a great implementation of this described by Drew Colthorp in the article [Flavoring: Flexible Nominal Typing for TypeScript](https://spin.atomicobject.com/2018/01/15/typescript-flexible-nominal-typing/)  which uses TypeScript branding but allows for implicit conversions. It looks like this:

```typescript
interface Flavoring<FlavorT> {
  _type?: FlavorT;
}
export type Flavor<T, FlavorT> = T & Flavoring<FlavorT>;
```

Which can then be used as (example from the article):

```typescript
type PersonId = Flavor<number, "Person">
type BlogPostId = Flavor<number, "BlogPost">
```

And now simple numbers can be assigned to both of these but not values cannot be cross-assign between variables defined as `PersonId` and `BlogPostId`:

```typescript
let p: PersonId = 1;
let b: BlogPostId= 2;

p = b; //error
b = p; //error
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgGIBs4DcD2VQDmAPBtngCoB8yA3gLABQyyA+mAJ4AOEA-AFxpMuKOQDcjAL6MO3QWShFyAGjnCqyALzJyyAGSq8hEkIqVxDaVxQAFaAGccIAJIATTQYUgArgFsARtAqAES2UA4gQZSWsgBC6DgE1jh2YK7upMJE3v6ByEFxCUkpkYyM6BBgyJwCoeFpWgCM5uWVfgIFicmpbloATOaMnO5+osgA9GPQUHiMfu6coxNTMwxAA)

---

With minimal changes, the code in the question can be changed to define `Id` type as:

```typescript
type Id<T> = Flavor<number, T>;
```

And then it can be used by passing a string:

```typescript
type Thing = { id: Id<"Thing"> };
type NotAThing = { id: Id<"NotAThing"> };
```

Which now makes the example behave as expected: [Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgGIBs4DcD2VQDmAPBtngCoB8yA3gLABQyyA+mAJ4AOEA-AFxpMuKOQDcjAL6MO3QWShFyAGjnCqyALzJyyAGSq8hEkIqVxDaVxTkAFoU21kwACYCAks6IAiW4S+UJcxkUADkcMABBXxACBxonV2QPbzDI6IJ-ZkDGS1lk9S1SYSIQAFcAWwAjaBUqc0YEHBAAZzBkMDsYgXS4xmYXAQBGACYAZiVJeoZGlraQcKjOggFUxfsteiYEgQAWAFYANgmGbIsGGFKQBDBgJuQCCDB0gAoBpM8fJf8ASlo+5Cgj1KUBAyC8NmgEAA5M12hC4X5zFIzhcrjc7g8wKsXm9kl5sV9KL9NsxmICwMDQeDITC4Sh5m04AiYl4kTkzgB6DnaOywgDueAA1s0AHSMTEvDqEEUub7mTEEwjPBlrGIy5xy9mMLk84CwjpQHB82FMxrlTjATDo0HQQ1QcWPF4q9LqzUMBULSVLV2iIA)