# Is there a way two have a TS error if we declare two type as string and compare them?

Tags: typescript

I am trying to find if there is a way two have an "type error: you compare two different types.

For exemple in this case :

```
type String1 = string;
type String2 = string;

const firstString: String1 = 'something'
const secondString: String2 = 'something'

if(firstString === secondString) // here even if the string value as the same, have an error because type as different.
```

Comment: You would need to "brand" the strings like this: https://tsplay.dev/mq3jYw - however, this makes working with these branded strings significantly more *annoying* since you would have to use assertions everywhere or someway to add in the brand property at runtime.

Comment: type-fest provides the `Opaque` type for this purpose: https://github.com/sindresorhus/type-fest/blob/main/source/opaque.d.ts

Comment: You're mixing compiletime types (TS) with runtime types (JS). Moreover, TS's type system is for structural equality. There is no nominal typing `String1` and `String2` are exactly the same because they are both just aliases to string. And a string is the same as a string. You *may* want branding, which can provide nominal-like type (types that *aren't* the same even if they are over the same data). But branded types are quite annoying to deal with. I'd think carefully about using them, if I were you. What's the use case? Maybe there is a better way to go about it.

Comment: @Bbrk24 I'd recommend using [this implementation of Opaque types](https://spin.atomicobject.com/2018/01/15/typescript-flexible-nominal-typing/). The author calls them "flavours" but really it's still the same concept. They are a lot easier to deal with than the hard branded types, since the "flavours" can be implicitly typed and require less type assertions or other structures around them to ensure the type is the type, even though, you know it is.

Comment: @VLAZ. In my case in have several interface and each of them have an id (which is a string). And I would be like two be sure if I compare two Id. This two id are from the same interface

Comment: @JonathanPujol then I do suggest the flavourings from the article I posted. They are really good at these. See my answer here: [How to accomplish stongly-typed ids in TypeScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71486513)

Comment: @VLAZ Indeed, it seems to be a good solution for my issue. Thank you.