# Two identical TypeScript interfaces with different names - how to make it DRY / avoid repetition?

Tags: typescript, types, dry

I'm working on a financial app that has "Bids" (offers to buy something) and "Asks" (offers to sell something).

```
interface Ask {
  price: number
  amount: number
}

interface Bid {
  price: number
  amount: number
}
```

How can I avoid repeating two identical type definitions? (They will always be identical)
I could have only one interface and call it `Offer` but it loses meaning and clarity.

I tried this:

```
interface Offer {
  price: number
  amount: number
}

interface Bid extends Offer {}
interface Ask extends Offer {}
```

But I get an eslint error saying `An interface declaring no members is equivalent to its supertype.` and there is no point extending the interface if I don't add something to it.

Comment: I'd argue that you should define `Offer` and use `Offer` everywhere. If `Bid` and `Ask` are no different from `Offer`, defining them (even with a type alias) as separate types might be confusing for a lot of people (even future you).

Comment: Thanks! But `Offer` is confusing, none of our users talk about offers, they only talk about bids and asks. Knowing that would you still recommend using Offer?

Comment: The word "offer" might be confusing, but the principle still stands: define and use one thing (`Bid` and `Ask` really look like two names for one thing, – `Transaction` maybe?). When I have difficulties finding a good word, GPTs (ChatGPT, Bing AI, etc.) are usually very helpful. Describe the idea to it, and ask for a one-word term for it.

Comment: @GuillaumeNo - FYI, I've updated the answer below to show using "favored" types. It's a nice middle-ground between no brand and branded.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a type alias:

```
interface Ask {
    price: number;
    amount: number;
}

type Bid = Ask;
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgIIGcDWyDeAoZQ5ABymCQC5kQBXAWwCNoBuAouOgexvCtsZZ4AvnjxgAnsRQAhYABNkAXjRZWeADYQwyOFQzZlOEmUrIALACYANDq48wVC8iGsA9K8IA9APwatyBipZBUNjcggqADYAdhsObl5zZzcPZB88OCUA5mR3ZAAeRWUAFQALYHRkCp11dU4Adwg5PCA)

Note that because TypeScript's type system is *structural* (based on the *shape* of types), not *nominative* (based on the names/identities of types), objects with the type `Ask` will be assignable to `Bid` variables/properties/parameters and vice-versa. TypeScript doesn't distinguish between them:

```
let a: Ask = { price: 42, amount: 2 };
//  ^? −−− let a: Ask
let b: Bid = { price: 67, amount: 4 };
//  ^? −−− let b: Ask
a = b; // <== This is allowed
```

Note that the type hint shown for `b` is `Ask`, not `Bid`.

If you want to maintain a distinction between the two types, you can use a technique described by Drew Colthorp in the article [Flavoring: Flexible Nominal Typing for TypeScript](https://spin.atomicobject.com/2018/01/15/typescript-flexible-nominal-typing/) (thank you [VLAZ](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3689450/vlaz) for pointing that out; see also VLAZ's [answer to a related question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71486801/157247)). The core of it is that you can differentiate the types by using an *optional* branding property, like this (but keep reading):

```
interface Offer {
    price: number;
    amount: number;
}

interface Bid extends Offer {
    __type__?: "Bid";
}

interface Ask extends Offer {
    __type__?: "Ask";
}
```

Since the property is optional, you don't have to specify it when creating instances, but it makes the types incompatible with each other (though you can easily convert from one to the other):

```
let a: Ask = { price: 42, amount: 2 };
//  ^? −−− let a: Ask
let b: Bid = { price: 67, amount: 4 };
//  ^? −−− let b: Bid
a = b; // <== Error: Type 'Bid' is not assignable to type 'Ask'.
       //              Types of property '__type__' are incompatible.
       //                Type '"Bid" | undefined' is not assignable to type '"Ask" | undefined'.(2322)
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgPIxtZBvAUMg5ABymCQC5kQBXAWwCNoBufQuWge2vEpoedwBfXLlCRYiFACFgAE2QQAHpBCyAzmgxY8hZAH09YAJ5EIBgPyUARDNlWWw0eGjwkyAIJqA1guURVGuiYUDisBAbGphbWnl72QiIANhBgyHCUscgAvDjEpBTIACwATAA0aZzcYJTFyIIsAPQNBAB65rjJqfSUttm5JGQQlABsAOzl7Fw8RXWNzchtuHB99EzITcgAPFk5AKJQUBxQlAAqJigA5LYXyMAaIBypcGpqwADmIHD0ychgHL-nZAXWIXAB0YV0G100N0Z1MGg4MDyHFMUGMQIi5wMNzgUBQoAQHFoRDgYGA3wg4Jh63m1OpcMuNjkVhudyojzSL3enwpv3+kUZsRZoIAFMUAMzFYoASlwQA)

In the article, Colthorp takes it further by creating a reusable generic `Flavor` type:

```
interface Flavoring<FlavorT> {
    _type?: FlavorT;
}
type Flavor<T, FlavorT> = T & Flavoring<FlavorT>;
```

which you'd use in your code like this:

```
interface Offer {
    price: number;
    amount: number;
}

type Bid = Flavor<Offer, "Bid">;

type Ask = Flavor<Offer, "Ask">;
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgGIBs4DcD2VQDmAPBtngCoB8yA3gFDKPID6YAngA4QD8AXGplxRyAbjoBfOuy4CyUIuQA0soVWQBeZOWQAyFXkIlBFSmLqhIsRCgDyMGNFoMmHfEn4gArgFsARtDEmZDhvHE9wDx9-KDFJKU4UACFgABMNfXk7ByhlACJklNzTOniZAEEAZwBrdNIhIizoPMqqorN0CDBg-hb0mmRXYHdkABYAJmUQsIjkMeRxMQB6RcYAPW46Dq7ffgK+gbcIfgA2AHZJ0PCwfhH5pZXkdbo4dN8RZGXkInVNAFEoKB4fjkBLIADkBTByGAFWQIBwXTgFQqwAIIDgvg6yDAOGxoLBLTBADpnEEPg8yZStAlYTgYAccFwoOxwcxWAk2VC4FAUKAEDhvBw4GBgJiICSqZ8qdKQTIwflUrkoTC4QjgsjUeixdjcdIUPKWkqiQAKMYAZjGYwAlHQgA)

The same tests with `a` and `b` show that you can't assign the one to the other.

Finally, you could use fully-branded types by actually including the `_type` (or `__type__`) property in the instances and not making them optional. I find it handy to do that sometimes because I can see those properties in the debugger and I can use them for type narrowing in code that works with `Offer` instances. But sometimes you don't want the extra properties cluttering up the objects, hence the "flavor" approach above. Example of full branding:

```
interface Offer {
    price: number;
    amount: number;
}

interface Bid extends Offer {
    __type__: "Bid";
}

interface Ask extends Offer {
    __type__: "Ask";
}

let a: Ask = { price: 42, amount: 2, __type__: "Ask" };
//  ^? −−− let a: Ask
let b: Bid = { price: 67, amount: 4, __type__: "Bid" };
//  ^? −−− let b: Bid
a = b; // <== Error: Type 'Bid' is not assignable to type 'Ask'.
       //              Types of property '__type__' are incompatible.
       //                Type '"Bid"' is not assignable to type '"Ask"'.(2322)
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgPIxtZBvAUMg5ABymCQC5kQBXAWwCNoBufQuWge2vEpoedwBfXLlCRYiFACFgAE2QQAHpBCyAzmgxY8hZAH09YAJ5EIBygCIZsiy2Gjw0eEmQBBNQGsFyiKo3pMKBxWAgNjU3NkC3cPWyERABsIMGQ4ShjkAF4cYlIKZAAWACYAGlTObjBKUv1DEzM9SxiLZEEWAHp2ggA9AH5cJJT6SmssnJIyCEoANgB2MvYuHkKysPrIqzkWttxOnv64MfomZD2AHkzsgFEoKA4oSgAVeuQAcmtX5GANEA4UuDUamAAHMQHB6ElkGAOFCXq8Yq8AHQhXR7XTo3TPUwaDgwXIcUxQYxvNYRPSfOBQFCgBAcWhEOBgYAQiDIjGnLrsrlYlCvTY2T7fKh-VKAkFgllQmHhXnRTwWJEACiKAGYikUAJS4IA)

Comment: "*The downside is that you have to either really have that property (as above), or use a type assertion initially when creating objects with those types.*" there is also a way to make the brandings less intrusive using what I described [in my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71486801) (which I didn't come up with, but read an article about - linked there). This provides similar protection from cross-assigning the two but it's more light-weight: `let a1: Ask = { price: 42, amount: 2};` just works, without having to pay attention to the brands https://tsplay.dev/mLrO2w

Comment: Thanks, that's beautiful! And irritatingly I had seen it done before, but didn't remember it. What do you think, should I edit it in, or do you want to post an answer, or (arguably) should we mark the question as a duplicate of that?

Comment: I don't think it's really a duplicate. The solution happens to work but I don't think it's the only way to do that. I think your answer covers everything nicely, I don't feel like adding another answer is worth it. You can add a note for the flavourings/opaque types if you wish. An answer that is only about that would be a bit anaemic :)

Comment: @VLAZ - I'm thinking the same, thanks. Thanks again for pointing this out!